# Whenever I try to install npm packages these WARN messages show up

Tags: node.js, npm, package

```
 1. npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
 2. npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools. 
 3. npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies. 
 4. npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2. 
 5. npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
```

I tried several commands like npm clean cache --force, and npm install npm @latest and others. However, this problem has not been solved.

Answer (score 0):

It means that some of the modules you have in your dependencies actually depend on these outdated packages. npm clean cache won't help unfortunately.
To rectify the issue you first need to analyse package-lock.json file - it contains all the tree of interdependencies of all modules involved in your. And then when you find all the modules depending on outdated modules you have potentially 3 options:

1. Find a package with the similar functionality which does not depend on outdated modules
2. Upgrade to a newer version in hope that the dependency also was upgraded
3. Post an issue to the author (if possible) to urge them to remove the outdated dependency